# Computing the order of growth of the reciprocal gamma function

Tags: integration

I am trying to estimate $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+it)}$ as |t| $\to \infty$.

I have read that this is an entire function of order 1 and so is equal to $C \log t$ as $t \to \infty$ but I cannot prove this.

Comment: $|1/\Gamma(1/4 + it)| \sim |t|^{1/4}\exp(\pi|t|/2)$ as $|t|\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: You can see for yourself [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BAbs%5BGamma%5B1%2F4%2Bit%5D%5Dt%5E(1%2F4)Exp%5BPi%2F2*t%5D,%7Bt,0,100%7D%5D).

Comment: According to your link, the result is true up to a constant! I would interested in a proof of this fact if you can point me to one !

Comment: Stirling's approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Error_bounds) holds in the right half-plane $\text{Re}(z)\geq c >0$ without any issue.

Comment: As an alternative, just consider the Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function and notice that $\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+it\right)\right|=\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+it\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}-it\right)\right|^{1/2}$.